# date filter query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am creating a date and time filter for a database.To query only result from date to date which will be selected in input field.
i have done coding and i think i have something missing in the code as it display **no records are found**

Form code :

```
<form method="POST" action="result_search.php">
Filter Result By Date :
From <input type="datetime" name="fdat" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
To <input type="datetime" name="tdat" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter Stats">
</form>
```

PHP code with pagination:

```
<?php
$from_dat=date($_POST['fdat']);
$to_dat=date($_POST['tdat']);
echo $from_dat;
echo "</br>".$to_dat."</br>";
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

$per_page = 10; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

$statement = "`user_data` where (`date_time_vote_1` AND `date_time_vote_2` AND `date_time_vote_3` AND `date_time_vote_4` AND `date_time_vote_5` AND `date_time_vote_6` AND `date_time_vote_7` AND `date_time_vote_8` AND `date_time_vote_9` AND `date_time_vote_10`) BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat' ORDER BY `poll_id` ASC"; // Change `records` according to your table name.

$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}") or die(mysqli_error($con));

if (mysqli_num_rows($results)!= 0) {

    // displaying records.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo "<tr><td class='active'>".$row['user_pin']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='info'>".$row['user_pin_entry']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='success'>".$row['user_vote_1']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_2']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_3']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_4']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_5']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_6']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_7']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_8']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_9']."</br>";
        echo  $row['user_vote_10']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='info'>".$row['ip_user_vote_1']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_2']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_3']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_4']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_5']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_6']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_7']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_8']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_9']."</br>";
        echo $row['ip_user_vote_10']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='success'>".$row['date_time_vote_1']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_2']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_3']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_4']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_5']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_6']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_7']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_8']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_9']."</br>";
        echo  $row['date_time_vote_10']."</td></tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
}
else {
     echo "No records are found.";
} 
 // displaying paginaiton.
echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page,$url='?');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following part seems to be the issue

```
(`date_time_vote_1` AND `date_time_vote_2` AND `date_time_vote_3` AND `date_time_vote_4` AND `date_time_vote_5` AND `date_time_vote_6` AND `date_time_vote_7` AND `date_time_vote_8` AND `date_time_vote_9` AND `date_time_vote_10`) BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat'
```

because

```
SELECT ('2015-08-26' BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31') AND ('2015-08-27' BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31') AND ('2015-08-28' BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31')
```

returns `true`, whereas

```
SELECT ('2015-08-26' AND '2015-08-27' AND '2015-08-28') BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'
```

returns `false`

Comment: will i create a long query and join it using and?

Comment: change the date comaprison part to `(date_time_vote_1 BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat') AND (date_time_vote_2 BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat') AND (date_time_vote_3 BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat')` and so on for all your date fields

Comment: no luck..again no records are found.
i database i have time-stamp (date and time both) in a single column.that may be the issue???

Comment: make sure all of your fields have valid and `NOT NULL` dates and these dates lie within the dates you are passing from your form.

Comment: some of the fields from database are `null`.so i want to exclude that using the query and the query should work for that too.if no data than leave it if data available than check the where clause.

Comment: the query will not handle this unless you tell it to, if there are `NULL` values then this query will not work. You'll have to change you query like `(date_time_vote_1 IS NULL OR date_time_vote_1 BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat')` for all your fields

Comment: using `(date_time_vote_1 IS NULL OR date_time_vote_1 BETWEEN '$from_dat' AND '$to_dat')` filter doesn't work!

Comment: and retrieve all data from database.

Comment: what i'd suggest you to do is to start without any filter, then use just one field in your `WHERE` clause, if it works then add the second field and keep adding fields one after the other until the query gives no result, the field which causes no result is the problem and you should debug that. Also make sure that the fields in db and the values you pass from your form use same date format and contain same parts in same order i.e. date and time parts

Comment: yes i have set date to the correct format to match with the database.but filtering is the problem!